# Loading a new .nib at startup

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In my project I added a new Cocoa Touch class along with its .nib file.I called the file `ViewController`. As a result three files were added to my project a 
`ViewController.h` , `ViewController.m` and `ViewController.nib`. Now my project already had a default .nib file which I deleted.I then went to the properties settings and changed the `main interface` section to the name of my new nib file i.e `ViewController.xib` . I then added some content to my nib file however upon running the simulator my nib file content does not get displayed. Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong. These are the files currently in the project. I am using Xcode 6.

**Filename : ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

**Filename : ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

**FileName : AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

**FileName : AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

**FileName: main.m**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Also at the end I get this

```
Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
```

I am not sure if that is an error . Any suggestions on how I could resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the following in your applicationDidFinishLaunching

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:
[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]; 
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] 
 initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```

Comment: what about the last 3 statements `self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;` ?

Comment: The first one set the color as white, you can do so if you want, but your viewController will be covering the entire screen, right? The last line brings it to front. You can keep them in your code.

Comment: Ill give this a try later today and post back. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the ViewController as your rootViewController in your AppDelegate.m. First you need to import ViewController.h then:

```
self.window.rootViewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    return YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you delete the app from your simulator or device before rebuilding from scrtach? Often time .xib changes do not take effect until you do.